# Does spring integration jpa:outbound-channel-adapter provide hooks/callbacks for successful write?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

**Requirement**: Need a way to tell if a `Message` sent on the `jpa:outbound-channel-adapter` successfully made it to the DB or not? This is required, because as soon as we get the confirmation of successful write to DB a new pipeline has to be started.

The [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa-outbound-channel-adapter) does not have any parameters related to callbacks/hooks.
One solution is to use `synchronization-factory`. However `synchronization-factory` requires that it should be inside a `poller` block. Then the question is does `poller` make sense in an **outbound** setting?

Any other design suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to add into the `jpa:request-handler-advice-chain` of that `jpa:outbound-channel-adapter`. And start a new pipeline from the `successChannel` of that component.

However it isn't clear why you don't mention that you have an exception when your data can't make it into the DB. That's suspissions...